# Spring boot OAuth2 - JWT tokens in a cookie instead of GET request

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring boot application that is using OAuth2 and it works good. The problem is that the access token and the refresh tokens is accessible with a GET request which making the tokens to be exposed and i want to switch it so the token will be stored in a cookie (httpOnly of-course) and will be accessible by the server side only.
I've searched the internet to find some example or explanation on how to do that but found nothing so far.

The only thing I've managed to do is to override the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method and store the tokens in a cookie but it is only half work the question is how to override Spring's OAuth2 to use this cookie instead reading the token from the request headers?

And how to override the default access (GET request) so the tokens will be stored only in a cookie only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "being stored in the session which making the tokens to be exposed"? Exposed in which way?

Comment: And what, specifically, makes you think they're being stored in a session?

Comment: @Henry , my bad, what i wanted to say is that the tokens are accessible through a GET request which expose them because they can be accessed from the client, and instead i want to store them in a cookie with httpOnly flag so they will be accessible from the server side only.

Comment: @chrylis my last comment answers on your question as well